# reducing apk size with vector drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to reduce the apk size of my android app.

I've read this guide: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

I already converted all my images to vector drawable, so they are sightly smaller.

But when i click on generate apk, android studio does create an `PNG` version of each of my vector drawable and package it together with the vector in the final apk

So it was pointless since now my apk has both vector and png...

how can i force android studio to use the vector drawable making the user scale the images at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

As the official doc says:

> If the minimum API level is Android 4.4 (API level 20) and lower, and
>   you haven't enabled the Support Library technique, Vector Asset Studio
>   generates PNG files.

so check if your project meets this condition.

Comment: So it sounds like there are two solutions: 1. Set the minSdkVersion to 21 or higher. 2. Enable the "Support Library technique" (whatever that is).

Comment: Our minimum SDK version is 21, still, PNG images are being generated. Any Clue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled upon this problem recently. The solution is to enable the vector drawable support library. That way it wont  generate the additional PNG files required for older versions of android. You can do that in the build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

You can find more info here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution